# Created a bash shell using forkpty(). It seems programs launched by this shell launch with SIGINT ignored. Why?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, pty

I have a C program that uses forkpty to execute a bash shell.  I'm finding that the programs launched by this shell are launched with SIGINT ignored, so when I send a Ctrl-C to the shell they never close.

example:

```
int masterFd;
char* args[] = {"/bin/bash", "-i", NULL };
int procId = forkpty(&masterFd, NULL, NULL,  NULL);
if( procId == 0 ){
  execve( args[0], args, NULL);
}
else {
   // Simple code that reads from standard in and writes to masterFd.  
   // I also register for Ctrl-C and write it to masterFd if caught
}
```

Other control characters seem to make it through, ctrl-D, ctrl-? etc.  However, whenever I look at the status of a process launched by the new bash shell it appears as if SIGINT is masked out.

```
MyShell:# sleep 1000

StandardTerm:#  ps -ef | grep sleep
root    26611  19278  0  17:44  pts/1   00:00:00 sleep 1000
root    26613  32376  0  17:44  pts/1   00:00:00 grep sleep

StandardTerm:# grep Sig proc/26611/status
SigQ:    0/256428
SigPnd:  0000000000000000
SigBlk:  0000000000000000
SigIgn:  0000000000010006   <- THE 6 IS THE PROBLEM
SigCgt:  0000000180000000
```

SigIgn has the 2 bit set, which means 2 (SIGINT) is ignored.  if I do the exact same thing, but run sleep (or cat a giant file or whatever) in a standard terminal, this bit is cleared.  What am I doing when I launch my pty bash that is causing it to create grandchildren programs with SIGINT ignored?

Moreover, if I send a SIGINT signal to the process

```
StandardTerm:# kill -2 26611
```

nothing happens.  What's strange is when I send the same command to the bash shell I forkpty'ed IT works, because that bash shell is not ignoring SIGINT.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the *termios(3)* man page.  You use '**NULL**' as the *termios* (third) argument in the *forkpty* call, meaning that the '**c_iflag**' *termios* structure value would be undefined, and inherits the value of its parent process. (Thank you @djc6535)

```
pid_t forkpty(int *amaster, char *name,
              const struct termios *termp,
              const struct winsize *winp);

struct termios
  {
    tcflag_t c_iflag;       /* input mode flags */
    tcflag_t c_oflag;       /* output mode flags */
    tcflag_t c_cflag;       /* control mode flags */
    tcflag_t c_lflag;       /* local mode flags */
    cc_t c_line;            /* line discipline */
    cc_t c_cc[NCCS];        /* control characters */
    speed_t c_ispeed;       /* input speed */
    speed_t c_ospeed;       /* output speed */
  };
```

From the *termios(3)* man page:

```
    c_iflag flag constants:

    IGNBRK Ignore BREAK condition on input.

    BRKINT If IGNBRK is set, a BREAK is ignored.  If it is not set but BRKINT is set, then a  BREAK  causes  the  input  and  output
           queues to be flushed, and if the terminal is the controlling terminal of a foreground process group, it will cause a SIG‐
           INT to be sent to this foreground process group.  When neither IGNBRK nor BRKINT are set, a BREAK reads as  a  null  byte
           ('\0'), except when PARMRK is set, in which case it reads as the sequence \377 \0 \0.
```

The relevant portion being '**When neither IGNBRK nor BRKINT are set, a BREAK reads as a null byte ('\0')**

<strike>So everything is working as expected.</strike>

<strike>Perhaps build a *termios* structure to set various important flags?</strike>

Comment: Careful, the termios structure isn't 0, but rather the POINTER to the termios structure is 0.  That doesn't mean that IGNBRK or BRKINT are unset it means that they are undefined as parameters.  When they are undefined as parameters, when termios is null, the child process is supposed to inherit the settings of the parent.  I have verified that this is the case by using tcgetattr().  Moreover, remember that bash is the child of the forkpty call, and it does respond to interrupts.  It's the children of bash that ignore them.

Comment: But just to be sure I created a termios struct with the defaults and IGNBRK and BRKINT set properly.  Same behavior.  I am fairly confident the shell itself is generating the break, but the children are being launched to ignore those breaks.

Comment: Thanks, I'm wondering if it's a combination of forkpty and execve?  Looking into it.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you remove the '-i' argument to bash?  The '-i/interactive' flag changes how bash handles several signals, SIGINT included.  Actually, can you try a different executable?  I leaning towards bash changing it's environment, and forkpty is working properly until then

Comment: Sorry, no it doesn't.  I've tried every combination of -i and -l (both on, both off, and each on in absence of the other), no difference.